# Converting exponential number to decimal in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to convert the below value to proper decimal values.

```
column_name
3.4202999999999997E-2
```

I tried these steps:

```
TRY_CONVERT(decimal(30, 10), [column_name]),
CAST([column_name] AS float)
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What data type is the value currently?

Comment: You tried things, what was the outcome, and what did you expect?

Comment: The oputcome was either null or a 0. I am expecting it to be something like this - 0.00034202999

Comment: But `3.4202999999999997E-2` is `0.0342030000`, not `-0.00034202999`. And that doesn't answer my original comment...

Comment: yes, Thats right. sorry my bad. But am getting either null or a 0 value here. Varchar it is

Comment: What is the **data type** of `column_name`?

Comment: If the value is literally `3.4202999999999997E-2` as a `VARCHAR`, [it would work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e82e927447db19841bef4843790679d8) (as in, it would not result in `0`). This suggests you've got something different.

Comment: the datatype is varchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value is a `float` then this will automatically be able to be explicitly converted to a `decimal`:

```sql
DECLARE @f float = 3.4202999999999997E-2;
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(30,10),@f);
```

If it is a string based data type, you really need to address that; it is not a suitable data type for a numerical value. The value `'3.4202999999999997E-2'` is *not* a valid `decimal` value, so you will need to first convert it to a `float`, and then a `decimal`:

```sql
DECLARE @v varchar(50) = '3.4202999999999997E-2';
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(30,10),CONVERT(float,@v));
```

If you get errors from that, then you have values that are not valid `float` values; this is one reason why storing numerical data is so foolish. You can **discard** the bad data using `TRY_CONVERT`:

```sql
DECLARE @v varchar(50) = '3.4202999999999997ee-2';
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(30,10),TRY_CONVERT(float,@v));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your input data type is text based, so let's say NVARCHAR. If you convert is to float, you might lose precision. It really depends on your use case, but you can try with a manual processing of the exponential formula like this (more detail below):

```
SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(c1, CHARINDEX('E', c1)+1, 1)
        WHEN '-' THEN CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(c1, 1, CHARINDEX('E', c1)-1) AS decimal(30,20)) / CAST(POWER(10, SUBSTRING(c1, CHARINDEX('E', c1)+2, 99)) AS INT) AS decimal(30,20)) 
        WHEN '+' THEN CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(c1, 1, CHARINDEX('E', c1)-1) AS decimal(30,20)) * CAST(POWER(10, SUBSTRING(c1, CHARINDEX('E', c1)+2, 99)) AS int) AS decimal(30,20)) 
    END AS [ResultValue]
FROM dbo.test
```

I used this as test to simulate:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.test
CREATE TABLE dbo.test
( c1 NVARCHAR(50) )

insert into test (c1) values ('3.4202999999999997E-2')
insert into test (c1) values ('1.2342999999999997E+3')
```

This is the parsing in steps which parts then used in the CASE statement:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(c1, 1, CHARINDEX('E', c1)-1) AS [BaseValue],
        SUBSTRING(c1, CHARINDEX('E', c1)+1, 1) AS [ShiftDirection],
        POWER(10, SUBSTRING(c1, CHARINDEX('E', c1)+2, 99)) AS [ShiftAmount]
FROM test
```